# Multiple defaults for Locale in Spring Web MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, localization, internationalization, locale

I would like my Spring-MVC-based web application to default to SK locale when CZ locale is passed in, however any other locale should default to EN.

The site I am designing should automatically display in Slovak language when visited from a computer with either a Czech or Slovak locale setting. Otherwise, the site should just default to English. How could I achieve this? Should I subclass the `org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor` and write custom code, or is there a config-only way of achieving this? I can imagine that German speaking countries could have the same sort of requirement, like default to DE if visited from Germany or Austria, otherwise default to EN...

Answer (score 3):

You will not need to subclass LocaleChangeInterceptor . LocaleChangeInterceptor  detects  change in locale via a request parameter 'Locale' .

You'll need to configure the interceptor and locale specific property files . After this you could use

```
 <spring:message code="propertyVal"/>
```

to display them.Check [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example.html) for a sample configuration.

You could also use CookieLocaleResolver which is a "LocaleResolver implementation that uses a cookie sent back to the user in case of a custom setting, with a fallback to the specified default locale or the request's accept-header locale. "

Comment: i am using all of that okay, i can switch between languages, i just would like to default to SK locale when someone visits with CZ locale in header. Otherwise I would like to use the default EN locale configured in the CookieLocaleResolver

Comment: somehow i figured this one was used by default and only passing a cookie could explicitly override the locale... okay... still i don't see how this would be used to default to SK when CZ was found in the accept header